# Textmate doesn't recognize wget

Tags: wget, textmate

Maybe stackoverflow is not for posting this kind of questions, and if it's that way, i apology..

I got a problem when using Textmate, it doesn't recognize wget, when i try to run wget from it, it says:

```
wget: command not found
```

The sh bundle is using the last version of ssh (the homebrew one, i set the TM_SHELL & SHELL manually) and everything so far seems to work (all other commands) but not wget, any clue?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to say, running wget from console works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess wget is installed at /usr/local/bin via brew or something... By default, that directory is not in TextMates PATH environment variable.

You can extend the environment either by setting PATH to $PATH:/usr/local/bin under Preferences -> Variables or by setting

> PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

in your ~/.tm_properties file (That would /User/yourusername/.tm_properties, just in case  you are not familiar with the "~" alias to your home directory).

Comment: I already have /usr/local/bin in my path, was the first thing i tried, but i never set it in the Textmate self PATH variable, good point, tried that and worked :) Thanks!